# changing colour of parent element of unchecked checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and I have many checkboxes there, which value is puller from database:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="schedule_1st draft ?">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" offval="no" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="schedule_Art work ?">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" offval="no" disabled="disabled"></td>
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="" aria-describedby="schedule_On sys ?">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" offval="no" disabled="disabled"></td>
```

After grid is loaded, I want to change background colour of cells checkboxes of which are unchecked. I'm trying:

```
if ($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")) {
        $(this).parents().css('background-color', '#666');
    }
```

but nothing gets changed.

Any better suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent().css('background-color', '#666');
```

Comment: yes that worked... but logically it's the same as code above?... thanks anyway

Comment: Not really. In your code, you are doing `if($(selector))` wich will alway return true since jQuery is always defined. If you want to check if the element exist, you need to check the length `if($(selector).length)`. Then, `$(this)` in the `if(){}` doesnt mean elements passing condition, but element calling the function. At last, `.parents()` (with an 'S') will get EVERY parent from the element to the body.

Comment: An other solution, who is slower and more code, would be to use an each : http://jsfiddle.net/8VZ4E/

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check to see what `$(this).parents()` is actually returning in the console (is it finding the td and tr's) but my first thought would be that you might need to pinpoint the  using jQuery's closest() method:

```
$(this).closest('td').css('background-color', '#666');
```

[jQuery: closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Traversing/closest&redirect=no#expr)